# Getting the first and/or last record(s) in a column

Tags: sql

What are the orders of the following SQL statements from most to least efficient?

**NOTE:** Let the syntaxes be language agnostic (i.e. use `TOP 1` in the proper place instead of `LIMIT 1`). Assume that `table_name` is the name of the table, `column_name` is the name of a column, `id` is the name of a column with a primary key, and the table has tens of thousands of records.

1. `SELECT FIRST(column_name) FROM table_name`
2. `SELECT column_name FROM table_name LIMIT 1`
3. `SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE id=1 --assumes the first id is 1`
4. `SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE id=(SELECT MIN(id) FROM table_name)`

AND

1. `SELECT LAST(column_name) FROM table_name`
2. `SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`
3. `SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE id=(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table_name) --assumes no values have been skipped`
4. `SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name)`

I don't know how to benchmark these statements but my *guess* is 2, 3, 1, 4 for getting the first record and 3, 2, 1, 4 for getting the last record.

Comment: Hmm. Didn't think about that one. I use MySQL but I haven't checked to see if `FIRST()` exists until now. However, my curiosity has peaked now so I suppose any that support the `FIRST()` and/or `LAST()` functions as well as the `LIMIT` operator will suffice.

Comment: @marc_s: SQLite and PostgreSQL also use `LIMIT`, I'm not familiar with FIRST or LAST though. The lack of a specified database makes me think MySQL or SQL Server but AFAIK SQL Server uses TOP not LIMIT, MySQL would be a reasonable guess.

Comment: @muistooshort: thanks for that heads-up - and yes, SQL Server uses the `TOP` clause (not `LIMIT`)

Comment: First and last are two new analytic functions coming in the 2012 release of SQL Server

Comment: Without 'where' or 'order by' you are not guaranteed to get the row with the lowest id when doing top 1 (or limit 1)

Comment: @idstam Is this the case for SQL in general or a specific flavor? I use MySQL and I've always been able to depend on a statement returning the results in the order in which they appear in the tables. Why do you say that?

Comment: As far as I know, no storage engine guarantees the order of returned rows unless you explicitly order them. There might be a suitable row in cache that is faster to return than to fetch a row from disk. In practice it has nailed me using MS-Sql a couple of times.

Comment: Hmm. In that case, number 4 might jump up to be the most efficient (aside from the unreliable number 3) if the results had to be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing but; FIRST and LAST are grouping operations. For the query engine to get their results it would need to collect the data first.

The others just need to return the first row it finds.
If there's an index on 'id' ordering it descending is not very expensive.

Comment: That's what I was leaning toward but I do not know enough about the implementations to say so.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted it because it answered my question but feel free to take a look at my massive edit for food for thought.